# Linux to linux USB storage?

Tags: linux

I was going to put together a small AoE setup for a small cluster, however 10Gb NICs are still rather expensive. Using superfast USB seems to provide the bandwidth I'm looking for at a much lower cost.

I presume this would require a host-to-host adapter?

In terms of software, while I suppose I cold use AoE (on top of an ethernet emulation layer) or iSCSI (on top of TCP/IP? ppp?). But is there a more direct way to implement a storage target on USB connected Linux?

(please note, I want to use a Linux system AS a USB connected storage device - not connect a USB storage device to Linux, nor implement a NAS server)

Comment: From some research the only "host to host usb adapters" I've found are USB 2.0. Doesn't mean they don't exist, but I think they've fallen out of use in favor of faster technologies. This reminds me of those "easy transfer" cables.

Comment: That was my concern - finding the hardware (since posting I found this: http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/file_storage.html which seems to solve the software problem)

Comment: http://www.cablewholesale.com/support/technical_articles/usb3_superspeed.php says "will allow for two host devices to be connected directly with a USB 3.0 crossover cable" and it seems that these are available.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of USB I would prefer to use Infiniband. It's much cheaper than ethernet 10G, well supported under linux. There is even a nice [blog](http://www.davidhunt.ie/infiniband-at-home-10gb-networking-on-the-cheap/) entry about similar problem.

Comment: aware of infiniband - but hardware is only cheap off eBay, requires expensive cabling too and I've only ever seen PCI[e] host adapters. Further, this means running the data on top of TCP/IP with all the complications regarding congestion avoidance. Thanks for the link though.